# Who disabled a job in SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent

I have a job in SQL server Agent. Now I see that this job is disabled. Multiple people can log in to server and can modify jobs (department policy).

I want to find out which user disabled this job.

Comment: If you cannot ask around and discover who made the change, nor have some kind of ticketing system for changes made to servers, it may suggest you need some *process* changes - limiting the number of people who have such high levels of access would be a good start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Time of the change is the only information you can query by default

```
SELECT date_modified FROM dbo.sysjobs
WHERE job_id = 'job_id'
```

In order to capture more information following measures can be setup ahead on  sysjobs:

- Update trigger
- Change Data Capture
- SQL Audit
- XE Session

Nice example: [SQL Server Agent logging actions and changes done to jobs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120579/sql-server-agent-logging-actions-and-changes-done-to-jobs)

Another one:

```
create trigger trigg on msdb.dbo.sysjobs 
after insert , update 
as 
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'name_of_mail_profile',
    @recipients = 'aaaa@ad.com',
    @body = 'New job creation or job modification alert',
    @subject = 'Automated Message' ;
```

Comment: Thanks. very useful. name will be more easier than job_id. `SELECT date_modified FROM dbo.sysjobs
WHERE name = 'job_name'`

Comment: @VenkataramanR, you are right. Job_Id and job_name both are equal identifiers for a some certain job